# stylesheet_link_tag :all with asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, erb

I'm attempting to upgrade a project originally done in rails 3.0 to rails 3.1 and I would like to enable the asset pipeline.  Being a rails 3.0 project, it used the `public/` folders for storing `css` `js` and image files.  I've found some of the views have

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
```

in them, and that without the asset pipeline, this results in the inclusion of all `css` files in `public/stylesheets`.

Is there any equivalent to this using the the asset pipline to say, include everything in `app/assets/stylesheets` ? or just all of the `asset/stylesheets` directories?  Or if there is a more *rails3.1 way* to do this I'm totally open to that too.  I'm just trying to find the correct way to upgrade this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asset pipeline includes your styles in `app/assets/stylesheets` by default. From the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

> Starting with version 3.1, Rails defaults to concatenating all
>   JavaScript files into one master .js file and all CSS files into one
>   master .css file. As you’ll learn later in this guide, you can
>   customize this strategy to group files any way you like. In
>   production, Rails inserts an MD5 fingerprint into each filename so
>   that the file is cached by the web browser. You can invalidate the
>   cache by altering this fingerprint, which happens automatically
>   whenever you change the file contents..

In your `/app/assets/stylesheets` directory, you should have a file called `application.css` (note the plain css extension) which should contain the following:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Also note that it *should* be all commented out like that, its how Rails reads it.

Comment: so I should be including `"application"` in the views then?

Comment: Your `/app/views/layout/application.html.erb` file should include in the header: 
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>